# Error in MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

Authorization failure.
Only zoom in and out option are coming but no map is coming up

> Authorization failure.
>   Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
>   06-19 17:05:09.219 13337-13404/? E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
>                                                               Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
>                                                               Ensure that the following Android Key exists:

```
package com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.fragment;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.R;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class FragmentThriller extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
        private MapView mapView;
        private GoogleMap mgoogleMap;
        private static final String KEY_MOVIE_TITLE = "key_title";
        public static FragmentThriller newInstance(String movieTitle) {
            FragmentThriller fragmentThriller = new FragmentThriller();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(KEY_MOVIE_TITLE, movieTitle);
            fragmentThriller.setArguments(args);

            return fragmentThriller;
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)          {
            View v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_thriller, container, false);

    //        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    //        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    //        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //
    //        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    //        mapView = mapView.getMapAsync();
    //        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    //        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    //
    //        // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    //        try {
    //            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    //        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    //            e.printStackTrace();
    //        }
    //
    //        // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    //        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    //        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated( view, savedInstanceState );
            mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        }



        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            mapView.onResume();
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mapView.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }


        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mgoogleMap = googleMap;
            mgoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom( new LatLng(28.6403159,77.376114) ,17);
            mgoogleMap.animateCamera( cameraUpdate );

        }
    }
```

## Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="in.goodiebag.carouselpicker"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/responsive"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="keyyyyyy"/>



        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="WebTechniQ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".fragment.digital_marketing"
            android:label="Digital Marketing">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".fragment.website_designing"
            android:label="Website Design and Development">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".fragment.DomainRegistration"
            android:label="Domain Registration">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Registration"
            android:label="Query Form">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


</manifest>
```